# My jrxml file creates an empty PDF file

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I created an `jrxml` file using `iReport Designer` tool. It works nice in iReport Designer tool. Now I am trying to compile that `jrxml` file using a `Java` program. The `MySQL` query is there in the `jrxml` file. I think the jrxml file is okay since it works as expected in `iReport Designer` tool.

When I run my Java program to compile and generate a `PDF` file of a report with `JREmptyDataSource`, it generates a `pdf` without any data filled, but the graphics ans static texts are there in the generated pdf. I know there is no data since I used a `JREmptyDataSource`.

Then I created a connection to my database. If things are okay, it should generate the `PDF` file with relevant data. Isn't it?

This is my code

```
try {    

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_db", "root", "123");
    System.out.println("INFO: Connected succesfully to the database!");

    JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("J:/reports using iReport tools/installmentListForACustomer.jrxml");
    // JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,new HashMap(), new JREmptyDataSource());
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,new HashMap(), c);
    JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, "fromXml.pdf");

    System.out.println("INFO: Success!");
} catch (Exception e) {

    System.out.println("EXCEPTION: " + e + " \n");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But the issue is, even though it generates a `pdf` file, it contains nothing. Not even the static texts and graphics. it is complete blank.

Query string is in the `jrxml` file. Database connection is successful as well. I cannot figure out why it generates an empty PDF.

Could you please explain to me why doesn't it generate a pdf file with relevant in database?

Answer (score 0):

There is a report configuration which **may** be an issue in your example:

```
When No Data
```

You can specifiy what your report should show when there is no data available. This could be one explanation (your query may don't work) and so nothing is displayed.

To check this you can try enter `When no Data = No Data Section` and add a "No Data" band in your report.